# COBOL to C++ data conversion

Tags: c++, cobol

I have requirement in which i need to convert -

MOVE HIGH-VALUES            TO W005-TEMP1.
MOVE LOW-VALUES             TO W005-TEMP2.

How can i code these two in C++ ?

Thanks
Akshay

Comment: HIGH-VALUES is x'FF', while LOW-VALUES is x'00'.  Extend for as many bytes as necessary.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/

Answer (score 4):

In COBOL, HIGH-VALUES represents one or more occurrences of the character that has the highest ordinal position in the collating sequence used. Similarly, LOW-VALUES represents the character having the lowest ordinal position in the collating sequence used.

The key here is "the collating sequence used". The **SPECIAL-NAMES** paragraph may be used to specify a customized collating sequence, but this is generally not done (still check it out). In the absence of a custom collating sequence, HIGH-VALUES is equal to X'FF' and LOW-VALUES is X'00' for both the EBCDIC and ASCII character sets.

To set W005-TEMP1 to HIGH-VALUES, you need to fill each byte it occupies with X'FF'. To set W005-TEMP2 to LOW-VALUES, you need to fill each byte it occupies with X'00'.